# How do I align another div next to an already centered item

Tags: css

I want to add an item next to a already centered item. I.E. I want Button 1a AND Button 2a to be centered together. And the spinner to be on the right keeping the button in the center.

```
    <div class="container-2">
      <div class="col-2-button">
        <button class="button">Button 1a</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2-spinner">
        <p>my spinner</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <button class="button">Button 2a</button>
    </div>
```

I[image: centred button]

Comment: BTW - I currently make a duplicate item on the left but make it hidden but that seems a of a rubbish solution

Comment: Are the two buttons known to be the same width always?

Answer (score 3):

This is quite easy with Grid layout:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.button {
  grid-column: 2;
}

p {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    <button>Button 1a</button>
  </div>
  <div class="spinner">
    <p>my spinner</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="button">Button 2a</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, not only a good answer but a learning opportunity for me. Never used grid as flexbox met my needs to date.

Comment: Grid is amazing. I recommend looking further into it!

Comment: Just done the leg work and watched David (Dave) Gray (not that one) and it is amazing. Lazy of me not to know. Reminded me of my java days when I knew only one layout Gridbag

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `position:absolute` and give up on the spinner being part of the page flow:

```css
.col-2-spinner p {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.container-2>* {
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-2-spinner {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-2">
  <div class="col-2-button">
    <button class="button">Button 1a</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2-spinner">
    <p>my spinner</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <button class="button">Button 2a</button>
</div>
```